# Why is my chrome extension icon working everywhere except in Chrome Web Store?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My icons for my chrome extension were set up correctly however the logo does not show in chrome web store.

I noticed I am not the only one with this problem because I can include Zoom Scheduler from official Zoom:
[image]

My extension has the same issue. Every icon works everywhere else, in chrome://extension, in the context menu and on the popup but not in the chrome web store.

Here are my  manifest.json settings:

```
"icons": {"16":"icon16.png",
        "32":"icon32.png",
        "48":"icon48.png",
        "128": "icon128.png"},
    "browser_action":{
        "default_popup":"popup.html",
        "default_icon": "icon32.png"
    }
```

When submitting the extension **from the google chrome developer dashboard**, I also set up a

- Small promo tile
- Large promo tile
- Marquee promo tile

however, I don't see those being used anywhere.

If that is relevant, my extension is currently: Status: Published - Unlisted

All previous answers and tutorials show that when you submit a chrome extension from the chrome web store developer dashboard, you have a "logo" section which I don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am motivated to write the answer to this question so that you don't have to spend one day thinking you're doing something wrong. It's not very intuitive and I hope you'll find it useful.

Here is the solution in two steps:

1. Open the Chrome Developer Dashboard and click your extension.
2. Scroll down and click on the blue link sending you to the **old dashboard**. You can set up your icon now

Screenshots:

1.
[image]

2.
[image]