# Is it possible to test a new version of my chrome extension with only a few specified users before publishing to everyone?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension tested perfect locally. But have some weird issues after publishing on Chrome Web Store.

Is there a way to test it NOT locally, but only to a few specified users?

Comment: Yes, you can publish your extension to some selected tester accounts, but you can only do that from the old dashboard (see [this answer about how to access it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62620953/3930351) )

Answer (score 1):

yes you can do that just upload your extension to drive and provide that drive link to limited number of people. I hope this will solve your problem. Happy to help.